# How do I properly end an IF ELSE statement in ASP Classic?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I’ve added an `IF` statement to a search results page so that it doesn’t run a long running procedure if the user doesn’t provide a notice id OR a notice date.  It works fine except that it is **not** displaying the New Search box below the error message.  An `End If` must be in the wrong spot or something but I can't seem to figure it out.

The “New Search” html should be displayed ALL THE TIME, not conditionally but it only seems to show if they do a valid search.

```
<%If task = "searchNotices" Then%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Notification System</TITLE>
<%Response.Write(NoEncode(GetStyleSheet("main")))%>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function popUpWin(thePage,theWidth,theHeight,theTop,theLeft,theName) {
        var features ="status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=" + theWidth +     ",height=" + theHeight + ",top=" + theTop + ",left=" + theLeft;

        var openit = window.open(thePage, theName, features);
        return;
}
-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<% <!-- begin what I added:-->

dim errorNeedsIdOrDate
errorNeedsIdOrDate = "<STRONG>Error: must input either a notice date or notice id.</STRONG><BR>"

IF isNull(noticedate) and isNull(noticeid) Then 
Response.Write errorNeedsIdOrDate
Else
<!-- end what I added-->
    Set rs = Obj.GetNoticeList (reterror, CInt(gSiteID), CLng(NoticeOwnerID), 9,cint(getPrint),cint(getFax),cint(getEmail),cint(getsuspend),noticedate, noticeid, null)

    if err <> 0 then LogError true, "notice_list.asp", "Call to NoticeData.GetNoticeList failed.", Err

    If retError <> "" Then 
    LogErrorMessage EVENT_ASP_EXCEPTION, true, "notice_list.asp", "Call to NoticeData.GetNoticeList failed.", retError
    Else
    %>
    <STRONG>Notice Search Results</STRONG><BR>
    <%if not rs.EOF then%>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <TABLE border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
    <TR class="DataHeaderRow">
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1"><STRONG>Send Now?</STRONG></TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">NoticeID</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">Notice Sent</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">NoticeType</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">HowToSend</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">Status</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">AccountNumber</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">Send To</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">Insured</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC" NOWRAP><font size="1">Policy(s)</TD>
        <form action="notice_resend.asp" method="get" id=form1 name=form1>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="passID">
        <input type="hidden" name="NoticeOwnerID" value="<%=EncodeHTML(NoticeOwnerID)%>">
    </TR>
        <%
        Do until rs.EOF
        'HowToSend,NoticeType,DueDate,CancelDate,DaysPastDue,AmountDue,LateCharge,
        'TotalDue,PolicyNumbers,AccountNumber,NoticeID,insuredname,agentname,insconame
        if (not IsNull(rs("DateSent"))) then
            if (rs("SendStatus") > 1) then
                Select Case rs("HowToSend")
                Case 1
                    sMediaKind = "print"
                Case 2
                    sMediaKind = "fax"
                Case 3
                    sMediaKind = "email"
                Case else
                    sMediaKind = ""
                End Select
            end if
        end if
        %>
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER">
<%              if (rs("HowToSend") = NOTICE_SEND_NOSEND) then  %>
                &nbsp;
<%              else                            %>
                <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="IDList" VALUE="<%=EncodeHTML(rs("NoticeID"))%>">
<%              end if                          %>              
        </TD>
        <TD>
<%              if ((CInt(gUserAccessLevel) > CInt(ACCESS_USER)) and rs("SendStatus")=0) then   %>
                <a href="javascript:popUpWin('ModifyNotice.aspx?noticeid=<%=EncodeURL(rs("id"))%>&refresh=no',500,300,350,150,'modifynotice')">
<%              end if  %>
                <font size="1"><%=EncodeHTML(rs("id"))%>
<%              if ((CInt(gUserAccessLevel) > CInt(ACCESS_USER))  and rs("SendStatus")=0) then  %>
                </a>
<%              end if  %>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <font size="1">
            <% If (sMediaKind <> "") Then %>
                <a href="javascript:popUpWin('ViewNoticeWindow.asp?noticeid=<%=EncodeURL(rs("NoticeID"))%>&kind=<%=EncodeURL(sMediaKind)%>',800,320,200,50,'displaynotice')">
            <% End If %>
                <%=EncodeHTML(rs("DateSent"))%>
            <% If (sMediaKind <> "") Then %>
                </a>
            <% End If %>
            </font>
        </TD>
        <TD><font size="1"><%=EncodeHTML(rs("Notice_name"))%></TD>
        <TD><font size="1">
        <%Select Case rs("HowToSend")%>
        <%Case 1%>
        Print
        <%Case 2%>
        Fax
        <%Case 3%>
        Email
        <%Case -1%>
        Suspended
        <%End Select%>
        </TD>
        <TD nowrap><font size="1">
        <%Select Case rs("SendStatus")%>
        <%Case 0%>
        Needs Sending
        <%Case 1%>
        Not Yet Confirmed
        <%Case 2%>
        Confirmed Sent
        <%Case 3%>
        Cancelled on resend
        <%End Select%>
        </TD>
        <TD><font size="1"><%=EncodeHTML(rs("AccountNumber"))%>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD><font size="1">
        <%=NoEncode(FormatSendTo(rs))%>

        </TD>
        <TD><font size="1"><%=EncodeHTML(rs("insuredname"))%>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD NOWRAP><font size="1"><%=EncodeHTML(rs("PolicyNumbers"))%>&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>

        <%rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        %>
    <TR>    
    <TD COLSPAN="15"><INPUT TYPE="submit" CLASS="MainFormBtn" VALUE="Mark For Resending"></TD>
    </form>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <%else%>
        No records were found.
    <%end if
End IF

%>
    <HR SIZE="1">
    <TABLE WIDTH=410 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=2>
    <TR>
    <TD colspan="2">New Search</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <form action="notice_list.asp" method="post" name="searchNotice">
    <input type=hidden name="task" value="searchNotices">
    <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC"><STRONG>Date&nbsp;notice&nbsp;was&nbsp;last&nbsp;sent</STRONG>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;mm/dd/yyyy</TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="10" name="noticedate"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC"><STRONG>Notice ID</STRONG></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="4" MAXLENGTH="10" name="noticeid"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD BGCOLOR="CCCCCC"><STRONG>How they are sent</STRONG></TD>
    <TD>
        Print<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" <%If getprint="1" Then%>CHECKED<%End If%>  NAME="getprint" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Fax<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" <%If getfax="1"  Then%>CHECKED<%End If%> name="getfax" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Email<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX"   name="getemail" value="1" <%If getemail="1" Then%>CHECKED<%End If%>>
        Suspended<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" <%If getsuspend="1" Then%>CHECKED<%End If%>   NAME="getsuspend" value="1">
    </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
<!--
    <TD COLSPAN="2" ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT STYLE="HEIGHT: 27px; WIDTH: 160px"
    type="submit"  CLASS="MainFormBtn" value="Search For Notices" id="Search"     name="SearchNotices">
-->     
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>
        <INPUT STYLE="HEIGHT: 27px; WIDTH: 160px" type="submit"  CLASS="MainFormBtn"     value="Search For Notices" id="Search" name="SearchNotices">
    </TD>
    </form>
    </TR>   
    </TABLE>
    <%
    End If
%>
```

Comment: If you were missing an `End If` it wouldn't work because the VBScript Engine would generate an `Expected End` error.

Comment: Yeah I believe it's just that an END IF is in the wrong place.  I want the New Search markup to always be output and it seems to get excluded when the first IF statement (with the two ifNull() checks) is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear and I don't understand what is the purpose of this script.
Anyway in the script above you missed an If statement closing at line 148:

You have 3 main If statements:

```
IF isNull(noticedate) and isNull(noticeid) Then '1st if
Response.Write errorNeedsIdOrDate
Else


    if err <> 0 then LogError true, "notice_list.asp", "Call to NoticeData.GetNoticeList failed.", Err 'an inline statement

    If retError <> "" Then '2nd if
    LogErrorMessage EVENT_ASP_EXCEPTION, true, "notice_list.asp", "Call to NoticeData.GetNoticeList failed.", retError

    Else
    %>
    <STRONG>Notice Search Results</STRONG><BR>

    <%if not rs.EOF then 'this is the 3rd if%>
```

And you had a closnig for only 2 of them:

```
    <%rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    %>
<TR>    
<TD COLSPAN="15"><INPUT TYPE="submit" CLASS="MainFormBtn" VALUE="Mark For Resending"></TD>
</form>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<%else%>
    No records were found.
<%end if
End IF
%>
```

If you add another `End If` statement here your script will run, but unfortunately I don't know if it does what it is intended to do. If there's anything else you'd like to ask, please provide more info about what data should this script get and what should it do.

Comment: The OP said *"It works fine"* so as [I have already stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316571/how-do-i-properly-end-an-if-else-statement-in-asp-classic#comment39483683_25316571) if it was missing an `End If` it would error, so any missing `End If` isn't the OP's actual problem. I question how useful answering this question in it's correct form is.